# How to change the structure of this makefile

Tags: makefile

I am new to handling makefiles and was provided with this one:

```
demo: demo.cpp vegas.o ranlxd.o
    g++ -o demo demo.cpp vegas.o ranlxd.o -lgfortran

vegas.o: vegas.F
    gfortran -c vegas.F

ranlxd.o: ranlxd.c
    gcc -c ranlxd.c

clean:
    rm -f  vegas.o ranlxd.o

distclean: clean
    rm -f demo
```

I use functions defined in the vegas and ranlxd files within the demo file. Now I want to change this so that all the codefiles are converted to object files first and then linked in the end so I tried the following:

```
demo: demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o
    demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o -lgfortran

demo.o: demo.cpp
        g++ -c demo.cpp

vegas.o: vegas.F
    gfortran -c vegas.F

ranlxd.o: ranlxd.c
    gcc -c ranlxd.c

clean:
    rm -f  vegas.o ranlxd.o

distclean: clean
    rm -f demo
```

This resulted in the error

```
demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o -lgfortran
make: demo.o: Command not found
make: *** [makefile:9: demo] Error 127
```

What am I doing wrong and what do I have to change in order to compile all the codefiles first? I highly appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your link command you forgot to actually call a program for the linker

```
demo: demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o
    demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o -lgfortran
```

should be:

```
demo: demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o
    g++ -o demo demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o -lgfortran
```

Comment: Something else you might look into to simplify your rules are make's automatic variables https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html

That would change the line to: 
`demo: demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o`

`    g++ -o $@ $^ -lgfortran`

Answer (score 0):

Samuel is right, you just forgot the link command (`g++ -o demo`). Make passed `demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o -lgfortran` to the shell and the shell complained that `demo.o` is not a command it knows.

I am just adding this answer to let you know about GNU make [Built-In Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules). If you use GNU make you could also rely on them and replace your compilation and link rules by a single `demo: demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o`. Yes, just that. GNU make knows how to build the `.o` files form your source files and how to assemble them to create the executable. Modify the [standard variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables), if needed (e.g. `FC := gfortran` and `CC := gcc`). Your Makefile could be as simple as, for example:

```
FC := gfortran
CC := gcc
LDLIBS := -lgfortran

demo: demo.o vegas.o ranlxd.o

.PHONY: clean distclean

clean:
    rm -f *.o

distclean: clean
    rm -f demo
```

But of course, if your goal is to learn make, it is probably better to write all these rules yourself.